# Firebase Messaging only works on separate devices

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently writing a feature for my app that allows the user to make a request to the worker in which they can accept or decline the job offer. I am using firebase messaging system. When I have two phones, the notification works and the worker can accept or decline, stated here:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String COLE_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.usub.COLE";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        LatLng customer_location = new Gson().fromJson(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),LatLng.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustomerCall.class);


        intent.putExtra("lat", customer_location.latitude);
        intent.putExtra("lng", customer_location.longitude);
        intent.putExtra("customer", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

However, I try to run the demo on my phone involving both apps, I receive the notification that the request has been made, however when the notification is clicked on, the app opens with no recollection of the data. My notification helper looks like this:

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final String COLE_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.usub.COLE";
    private static final String COLE_CHANNEL_NAME = "STRADTMANNSOLUTIONS Usub";

    private NotificationManager manager;

    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            createChannels();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannels() {
        NotificationChannel coleChannels = new NotificationChannel(COLE_CHANNEL_ID,
                COLE_CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        coleChannels.enableLights(true);
        coleChannels.enableVibration(true);
        coleChannels.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
        coleChannels.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        getManager().createNotificationChannel(coleChannels);
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if(manager == null)
            manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return manager;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public Notification.Builder getUsubNotification(String title, String content, PendingIntent contentIntent,
                                                    Uri soundUri)
    {
        return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),COLE_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify);
    }
}
```

Would anyone know why notification is losing all of its data or how I could open the app to a certain activity with new information from the press of a notification? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. If app is in the background then a notification is shown but it will not trigger onMessageRecieved, and data from that message is passed to the intent that is launched.
And u can use:-

```
getIntent().getExtras();
```

to retrieve the data sent via notification.

Check the docs [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive)